# Quarto unable to resolve external file in "include-before-body"

Tags: r-markdown, include, pandoc, quarto

I've long used R Markdown to create HTML documents. These documents rely on an external JS file that is accessed through HTTPS. Here is an example of the YAML header for this sort of R Markdown document:

```
---
title: "My R Markdown document"
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      before_body: https://example.com/myMathjax.js
---
```

This approach works. But I am now trying to switch from R Markdown to Quarto, and I can't find a way to include the JS file. The prescribed approach seems to be to use `include-before-body`, as in this example:

```
---
title: "My Quarto document"
format:
  html:
    include-before-body: https://example.com/myMathjax.js
---
```

But when I try to render Quarto documents that have this kind of header, I get an error message: "ERROR: Error resolving include-before- unable to open file [https://example.com/myMathjax.js"](https://example.com/myMathjax.js%22). The strange thing is that the file can be opened---indeed, R Markdown has no problem opening it and using it when rendering. How can I get Quarto to use this file?

I've searched SO, the Quarto documentation, and Github repositories. But none of them seem to speak to this particular question. As best I can tell, the problem lies either with pandoc or with the way that Quarto is communicating to pandoc behind the scenes.

I'm using Quarto 1.3.450 with VS Code and the VS Code Quarto extension.

*Update 2023-09-16:* further discussion at https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/6854.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, You can put the js-script file path as a src attribute of `<script>` tag in a html file and then use that html file in `include-before-body`.

**doc.qmd**

```
---
title: "My Quarto document"
format:
  html:
    include-before-body: included-content.html
---

## Quarto
```

**included-content.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/myMathjax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, shafee. I see that your code will work. But it doesn't get around the problem that I have in mind, which is the need to have an include file be local. I'm looking for a way to have all includes be remote (e.g., accessed via HTTPS).